# back button issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I am facing issue with the way back button works in Chrome.

I have a application where I am displaying a form in iframe inside the parents window.
So when the user clicks on back button the behavior on IE and Mozilla is that page in iFrame loads up again.
This iFrame page refresh when the user clicks browser back button is important in my case is because we need to keep a track of users who have logged in the application and accessed that iFrame content.

Now in Chrome the behavior of back button is different. When the user clicks on browser back button the user is taken back to previous page.

I need to alter this behavior for chrome and need to refresh the content in iFrame instead of moving back to previous page. 
Anyone kindly who have idea on this help me out.

PS: I cant use jQuery in application.

Regards,

Comment: Using the browser's back button to provide functionality for your website doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: I understand that. But its mandatory for us to track the users who have been to the application and exited without performing any activity.

Comment: I know this sounds like a lot more work, but the easy way to do that, would be to have some independent functionality of recording actions, including the "been to the application" action as a start. Then you should easily retrieve those that did nothing in the application, by searching who has only "been to the application", without performing further actions.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos cant do that too. Back button detection is how the clients want it to be. We did that for IE but later found that it breaks in Mozilla. Its a P1 now

Comment: If you make it the way I suggest, your client will never know it's not actually handling the back button. So, what if the user somehow bookmarks the iframe URL. Then when they hit the back button, they won't go to your site at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well the short answer is **you can't** and you shouldn't. becoz this behavior is inconsistent across different browsers and even future versions of mozilla and ie may also change it's behavior.

Still you have some alternatives to achieve this kind of behavior.
You can use HTML5's [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) where on hashchange event you can refresh you frame whenever you want.